# MS EXCEL: Returning quartile bounds and values from an array of numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to calculate the bounds of an array of values, I've used the QUARTILE function in Excel but I can't seem to get my head around it - How would I go about returning the bounds of the first quartile, second quartile, third quartile and fourth quartile? The reason I want to do this is to draw up a box-graph without showing the outlier values since they are making the graph un-readable.

The functions I'm using are:

```
=QUARTILE(C2:C6231,0)
=QUARTILE(C2:C6231,1)
=QUARTILE(C2:C6231,2)
=QUARTILE(C2:C6231,3)
=QUARTILE(C2:C6231,4)
```

- 0 shows min value (including outliers)
- 1 shows lower bound of the 2nd quartile
- 2 shows the median
- 3 shows upper bound of the 3rd quartile
- 4 shows max value (including outliers)

Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: You mean to say Ubound & Lbound ?

Comment: @RajeshS, How would I go about using Ubound and Lbound finding the Quartile bounds?

Comment: I can suggest you formula to find lower & upper median other than Quartile, will it work for you?

Comment: By definition, the quartiles include all of the data, including the outliers.  So you can't use quartiles to eliminate outliers.  You would need to use something like standard deviations to identify outliers or set limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to determine your range the outliers fall into. Using a normal distribution, you can choose how many standard deviations away from the mean you want. One standard deviation away should contain 68% of the population, Two should contain 95%, and three should contain 99%. Since you have outliers, I would use 1.5 Standard deviations as that should encompass approximately 86% of the total population; 43% above the mean, and 43% below the mean. In excel this can be done using the formulae:
`=MEDIAN($A:$A)-1.5*STDEV.S($A:$A)` and `=MEDIAN($A:$A)+1.5*STDEV.S($A:$A)`

This gives you an upper and lower bound. The upper bound is the top of the 4th quartile, and the lower bound is the bottom of the 1st quartile. Knowing this, you can use the difference in between them to calculate the inner bounds.

```
Upper Bound - Lower Bound = Range
Range / 4 = Interval
Lower Bound = Lower bound of 1st Quartile
Lower Bound + Interval = Upper bound of 1st quartile, Lower bound of 2nd quartile 
Lower Bound + 2*Interval = Median, Upper bound of 2nd Quartile, Lower bound of 3rd quartile
Upper Bound - 2*Interval = Median, Upper bound of 2nd Quartile, Lower bound of 3rd quartile
Upper Bound - Interval = Upper bound of 3rd quartile, Lower bound of 4th qartile
Upper Bound = Upper Bound of 4th qartile
```

The vb code for this would look like this:

```
Public Sub Quartiles()
Dim Stdev, UpperBound, LowerBound, Interval As Double
Dim q1, q2, q3, q4 As String
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Stdev = WorksheetFunction.StDev_S(Selection)
UpperBound = WorksheetFunction.Median(Selection) + (1.5 * Stdev)
LowerBound = WorksheetFunction.Median(Selection) - (1.5 * Stdev)
Interval = (UpperBound - LowerBound) / 4
LowerBound = WorksheetFunction.Round(LowerBound, 3)
UpperBound = WorksheetFunction.Round(UpperBound, 3)
Interval = WorksheetFunction.Round(Interval, 3)
q1 = Str(LowerBound) + "," + Str(LowerBound + Interval)
q2 = Str(LowerBound + Interval) + "," + Str(LowerBound + 2 * Interval)
q3 = Str(UpperBound - 2 * Interval) + "," + Str(UpperBound - Interval)
q4 = Str(UpperBound - Interval) + "," + Str(UpperBound)
MsgBox ("Q1: " + q1 + vbNewLine + "Q2: " + q2 + vbNewLine + "Q3: " + q3 + 
vbNewLine + "Q4: " + q4)
End Sub
```